# How can I wrap a complex command with a shell script?

Tags: bash, shell-script

I'm using `optirun` from `bumblebee`. It is designed to start my 2nd GPU, run the command given, and shut down the 2nd GPU at the end.

A simplified example:

`optirun echo test | cat`

However there's a bug in `optirun` that requires that I now run a follow up command to force the GPU to shut down.

Can I easily wrap some complex command such as `echo test | cat` in a shell script such that I can run optirun, and then follow that up at the end with command (my workaround to the bug)?

The quoting and all seems to be an issue preventing me from doing this with a simple shell script.

Comment: But what is the actual problem you are suffering?  You told us that you **can** write a shell script that has some complex command, and that you have **some** problem with quoting.  Therefore, you actually **can't** write the script.  Maybe it will be better to post the script that you have and describe why you believe it does not work.

Comment: I need to run an `rmmod` command after `optirun` to get around `optirun` not shutting down the GPU (a bug that will be fixed in the next version). `optirun` takes any complex command such as the one I suggested. So I'd like my script just to call `optirun` with whatever I send it, and then when it's done execute the `rmmod` workaround. I could be overthinking this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm confident you're simply after `$@`, the argument list to a script.

Trivial example:

```
$ cat >cc.sh <<EOF
#!/bin/sh
head "\$@"
echo I AM DONE
EOF
$ chmod 755 cc.sh
```

Works with arguments:

```
$ ./cc.sh cc.sh 
#!/bin/sh
head "$@"
echo I AM DONE
I AM DONE
```

Works with STDIN/STDOUT

```
$ cat cc.sh | ./cc.sh | tail -n 2
echo I AM DONE
I AM DONE
```

Works with a mixture:

```
$ cat cc.sh | ./cc.sh -n 2 | tail -n 2
head "$@"
I AM DONE
```

Therefore:

```
#!/bin/sh
optirun "$@"
rmmod <mod> [perhaps >/dev/null 2>&1 if you need to ignore errors from rmmod]
```

Comment: The $@ should be inside double quotes, to preserve spaces etc in the arguments.

Comment: @icarus - you're 100% right!  I've just tested this, thanks for making me learn yet another details

Comment: @grochmal: you may want to read : http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls (to learn about quoting, and a lot of other very very useful things to know about) (for almost every shells, not just bash)

Answer (score 4):

If in your example of `optirun echo test | cat` you just want the `echo test` to be given to optirun, which is what happens when you type the example at the command line then

```
#!/bin/sh
optirun "$@"
rmmod workaround
```

is all you need. Put in a script called "myopti" and you can use `myopti echo hello | cat` and get the cleanup.

Comment: Lol, 7 seconds of difference (but you were first)

Comment: @grochmal, but you wrote so much more! I must take a typing lesson or 20. I think I can even earn a `disciplined` badge if I delete a +3 answer (hint hint) and you can get your just reward for your more comprehensive answer.